# HEX equivalent colors conversion using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I have a hex color for which I add 0D to give opacity. Which when rendered becomes RGBA(x, y, z, 0.05).
The adding of opacity is causing me issues that I want to avoid.
The equivalent color:

```
#ff55970D => rgba(255, 85, 151, 0.05) is #fff6fa
```

Is there a way I can convert `#ff55970D` to `#fff6fa` directly using JavaScript without adding opacity '0D' or having it converted to RGBA?

Comment: The "equivalent color" (without alpha component) depends on the background color.

Comment: @trincot - #ff5597 with 5% opacity by adding '0D' is #fff6fa(without opacity). Can you tell how to come from #ff55970D to #fff6fa programmatically?

Comment: Adding alpha means that whatever the background colour is, it will show through a little. Starting with `#ff55970D` will result in a different rendered colour e.g. black background will make the rendered colour darker but a white background will make it lighter. Without knowing what the background colour is we cannot say what the resultant colour should be.

Comment: You don't say what "issues" this is causing you.

Comment: @MichaelPhilips Here you can find a demo ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x4sLkgyc/)) of what trincot means, same color of block but with different backgrounds.

Answer (score 1):

The background determines what the effect of opacity is on a front color. In your example you seem to use a white background color (0xffffff).

Here is a function you could use to make the transition. You must provide the background color. I assume hex strings with 8 digits, and 6 for the background color.

```js
const colorComponents = hex => hex.match(/../g).map(s => parseInt(s, 16));

function convertToRGB(frontHex, backHex) {
    let front = colorComponents(frontHex);
    let back = colorComponents(backHex);
    let alpha = front.pop() / 255;
    return front.map((hue, i) => Math.round(hue*alpha + back[i]*(1-alpha)))
                .map(hue => hue.toString(16).padStart(2, "0")).join("");
}

let res = convertToRGB("ff55970D", "FFFFFF");
console.log(res);
```